# How does knexjs work with remote targets?

Tags: javascript, knex.js

On their [website](https://knexjs.org/#Installation-browser), KnexJS developers seem to claim that it is possible to bundle the library using Browserify and run it in the browser. How does that actually work? Don't you need a socket based connection to connect to target database (which browser javascript only partially supports via websocket specification)? Meanwhile, skimming through WebSQL (note: deprecated) specification, it seems to only support local SQLite based databases.

Comment: Where did they claim that you can run in the browser?

Comment: "Browser.   Knex can be built using a JavaScript build tool such as browserify or webpack. In fact, this documentation uses a webpack build which includes knex. View source on this page to see the browser build in-action (the global knex variable)." As seen on the link provided.

Comment: "Can I use Knex outside of Node.js?
Yes. While the WebSQL spec is deprecated, there is still an adapter that provides support. You will need to use a build tool like browserify or webpack for a browser build." And on their FAQ page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be used as a query builder for genarating SQL queries, but it cannot be used to execute queries from browser.